# How To Get 'Custom SEO Titles' For Each Paginated WordPress Page?

Tags: pagination, seo

Over the past few days, I've been exploring ways of optimizing my articles for a number of high volume keywords, instead of just 1 or 2.

Assuming I write an article on the **'Top 10 Richest Talk-Show Hosts',** which will be 3000 words in total, with about 200 to 250 words on each talk-show host. I will be creating page breaks for each person on the list, so along with the main **'Richest Talk-Show Hosts'** keyword, can I also rank standalone pages for keywords such as **'Ellen Degeneres Net Worth'** or **'Jimmy Kimmel Net Worth'?**

Is there anything I can do to optimize the standalone pages well for this? For low competition keywords, we should be able to rank by just mentioning the keywords in the post, but I'll need to include such keywords within the **title, H2 & H3's, IMG Alt Tags, etc,** so is it possible for each paginated page to have a separate title, while still being part of the main article?

This is an SEO strategy that could potentially bring in 1000s of visitors and allow bloggers to focus more on quality over quantity, so do let me know if any of you have any experience dealing with something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can quite easily access current page of paginated post with `get_query_var('page')`, though confusingly it will be `0`,`2`,`3`...

It wouldn't be hard to do whatever you want with title, conditionally on that. Any modern theme should have title theme feature enabled and have it easily filterable via hooks in `wp_get_document_title()`.